# GameCenter integration Complications?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, game-center

I called the code below to add Game center user banner pop up at the top of the screen, but it says Game is not recognized by Game Center:

I added this to my addDidFinishLaunching:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
if (error ==nil) {
NSLog(@"Success");
} else {
NSLog(@"Fail");
}
}];
```

For viewing leader boards, what code do I need to add to properly call it?

```
-(void)viewscores:(SPEvent*)event{
CODE HERE
 }
```

Comment: Did you try Apple's game center documentation? I believe they have quite a bit of sample code up there for these workflows...

Comment: I have read all of Apple Game Center Docs, Still can't fix out. When I run the game on device, it says: This Game is not recognized by Game Center. But on the simulator, it loads the banner and says SandBox.

Comment: I think I have got it, BUT do you know what the code is for viewing the leader boards?

Comment: did you add the app on iTunes Connect, enabled game center there and used that bundleID in your plist file ?

Comment: Many features will work perfectly in the iOS Simulator, but require you to do something (usually register your app for a service) on iTunes Connect for it to work on the actual device. Like Kaan said, follow the steps on iTunes Connect to enable Game Center in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like that :

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardVC = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
if (leaderboardVC !=nil) {
    leaderboardVC.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:leaderboardVC];
}
```

I hope it helps :-)